# can i draw a gradient background for a figureCanvas in Java

Tags: java, gradient, draw2d

I'd like to draw a gradient background for a FigureCanvas. Unfortunately the code which works for Composites or similars does not work for my FigureCanvas. Where it makes a perfect gradient background on my Composite it simply puts one color as background of my FigureCanvas.

Here is a snippetof how it works with all my other Controls.

```
Rectangle rect = parent.getClientArea();
Image newImage = new Image(parent.getDisplay(), 1, Math.max(1,
rect.height));
GC gc = new GC(newImage);
gc.setForeground(composite.getDisplay().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));
gc.setBackground(composite.getDisplay().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_BLUE));
gc.fillGradientRectangle(0, 0, 1, rect.height, true);
gc.dispose();
composite.setBackgroundImage(newImage);
```

Am i missing something here? Or is it simply not possible without overwriting or extending something (if so what?)? I also tried using the same backgroundImage as another Composite has it, where it works fine.

Thank you for answers!

Answer (score 0):

turns out the problem was not the FigureCanvas itself but GEF which overwrote it somewhere else.